# Automatic mail alert to customers on new products arrival in magento

Tags: email, magento, notifications

I want to add this feature in magento.Automatic mail alert to customers on new products arrival in magento upon on their subscription, its not like RSS but its just mail with the product alert alone. is there any extension or something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento already provides email alerts for when a product changes price or changes stock status (see `System>Config>Catalog>Product Alerts`).  If you have a look at the code in `Mage_ProductAlert`, you should be able to extend it to cover the case of a new product. I would guess that you'd want to offer customers the option to subscribe to alerts related to a category?  So, add a new model for `productalert/category` and extend the AddController with a `categoryAction()`

EDIT --

Actually, one "low-touch" option would be to use something like Feedburner to take the existing RSS category feed and send emails.  When you plug the feed into Feedburner, it will give you a link that users can click to subscribe to the email version of RSS.  It takes them away from your site, but does achieve the requirement without custom coding.

Comment: Yeah thanks Jonathan Day, i had gone through that too but i just wanted to know whether is there any extensions available already. I will work on it, thanks Jonathan Day.

Comment: There is an extension which might help you over this
http://www.fmeaddons.com/magento/out-of-stock-notification-extension.html